# Always failure the rspec testing in Github Action CI but pass RSPEC testing in local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a problem about Github Action CI. I changed the `deliver` method into `deliver_later` method in code. I ran the RSPEC testing in local and it's OK. However, I merged my branch into staging branch and it's failed in RSPEC testing. It runs in a long time and it's fail although these test are OK in local. I searched on Google but I didn't find the solution.
I used ruby version 2.6.6 and rails version 6.1.2. Thank you so much.
[This is error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNacQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

With changing to `deliver_later` your job does not get executed inline anymore. You mentioned that you merged it into a `staging` branch so I assume it will use a different environment. My best guess is that `staging` uses a different queue adapter than your local testing environment.

You can check this with e.g. with

```rb
ApplicationJob.queue_adapter
```

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#setting-the-backend